# R text mining association from CSV

Tags: r, csv, text, mining

I am using R for text mining and I have a question. I am importing in a CSV file with 4 columns. Two of the columns have strings in them one is the user input and the other is an official response, both are like sentences. Each row is a certain case/instance and there are over 4000 of them. I am trying to correlate certain key words in the user input to predict the response using associations. For example the user input "jump" often correlates to this response. Any help on how this can be set up? Thanks!

Comment: To get good answers and help others help you, please have a look at [how to ask a good question on stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: [Also read this.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610) If you haven't, check out the `tm` and `tidytext` packages, which should get you started.